# Changing OrientDB standard element key format

Tags: orientdb

**I'm wondering if the OrientDB element key "#:" format can take another 
format, for instance changing the colon to dash.**

*the problem with hash and colon that both are reserved for URI use (RFC 3986), and they cant
 be transferred by HTTP requests (Not Safe).*

any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrientDB HTTP Server allows to ignore # for RIDs when are in URL.

Comment: Thanks Lvca, I've already used the key without hashes, but the colon still a problem for some security measures, I think replacing it with underscore or dash is the best solution and re-parse it internally.

Comment: Nice idea, maybe dash? #12:33 -> 12-33

Comment: 12%3A33 should also work (colon url encoded to %3A (disclaimer: not tested with OrientDB, but should work)